# Android Implementing runOnUiThread

Tags: java, android, android-activity, graphics

I know there are a lot of questions similar to this, but I can't find the answer to my question.

I'm having troubles with my game. When the game loop for the SurfaceView is running, I can't change the visbility of the elements I want to make (in)visible.

This is caused because only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views, but I don't understand how to fix it...

```
07-28 19:07:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(15091): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-26727
07-28 19:07:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(15091):
android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that
created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
07-28 19:07:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(15091):    at 
android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:4650)
07-28 19:07:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(15091):    at 
android.view.ViewRootImpl.invalidateChildInParent(ViewRootImpl.java:877)
07-28 19:07:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(15091):    at 
android.view.ViewGroup.invalidateChild(ViewGroup.java:4066)
07-28 19:07:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(15091):    at 
android.view.View.invalidate(View.java:10275)
07-28 19:07:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(15091):    at 
android.view.View.setFlags(View.java:8385)
07-28 19:07:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(15091):    at 
android.view.View.setVisibility(View.java:5531)
07-28 19:07:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(15091):    at   
android.widget.ImageView.setVisibility(ImageView.java:1155)
07-28 19:07:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(15091):    at     com.coderogden.pongtennis.activities.SingleGameActivity.setInVisLife3C(SingleGameActivity.j    ava:84)
07-28 19:07:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(15091):    at 
com.coderogden.pongtennis.views.SingleGameView.outOfBounds(SingleGameView.java:319)
07-28 19:07:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(15091):    at 
com.coderogden.pongtennis.views.SingleGameView.update(SingleGameView.java:197)
07-28 19:07:20.913: E/AndroidRuntime(15091):    at  
com.coderogden.pongtennis.other.MainThread.run(MainThread.java:57)
```

Here is the important part of the code:

Activity-class contains loads of similar methods like this one.

```
public static void setInVisLife3C() {           
        life3C.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
```

Those methods are called from my SurfaceView-class, for instance from here:

```
public void outOfBounds() {

    // Player's side
    if (ball.getY() + ball.getRadius() > box.getBoxBot()) {
        playerLives--;
        playing = false;
        switch (playerLives) {
        case 4:
            SingleGameActivity.setInVisLife5P();
            break;
        case 3:
            SingleGameActivity.setInVisLife4P();
            break;
        case 2:
            SingleGameActivity.setInVisLife3P();
            break;
        case 1:
            SingleGameActivity.setInVisLife2P();
            break;
        case 0:
            SingleGameActivity.setInVisLife1P();
            playerLoses();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

This method is called from another method called update() which is also located in the SurfaceView-class!

The update() method is then called from the main thread (game loop) here:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    Canvas canvas;

    while (running) {
        canvas = null;

        // Try locking the canvas
        try {
            canvas = this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            if (canvas != null) {
                synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                    // Update game state here!
                    this.gameView.update();
                    More code down here!
```

Please tell me if you need more code to help me! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you answered your own question. You have to use *runOnUiThread* and *Runnable* to make changes to a view in non-UI thread. For example:

```
public static void setInVisLife3C() {           
    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            life3C.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks! But the problem is this: "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method runOnUiThread(Runnable) from the type Activity". And the method has to be static to be accessed from another class right (I access it from my SurfaceView class)?

Comment: @CoderOgden If understood correctly, your SurfaceView class should have a context reference that you can cast to an Activity.  Or you can pass a handler into a custom SurfaceView that you wrap to call back into the Activity.

Comment: Sorry, but I think you lost me in the first sentence, I'm new to android programming...

Comment: @CoderOgden also, calling activity methods like that is bad practise, you should consider using activity reference to call them.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Is this the right way to do it? [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656879/how-to-use-setters-and-getters-to-pass-data-between-classes-in-android] (answer by Luke Taylor)

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `runOnUiThread` from the UI thread. You need to call it from a separate thread. Try this

To edit @Gintas_ answer:

```
  public static void setInVisLife3C() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        life3C.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    }
                });
            }
        }).start;
```

Comment: This didn't work of the same reason as I commented on Gintas_ answer, I'm sorry.